# atlas sqoop hook access denied ("javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission" "register")

Tags: atlas

Error when registering metric on org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission" "register")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:585)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.checkMBeanTrustPermission(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1848)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:322)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
at org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter.reregister(JmxReporter.java:167)
at org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter.metricChange(JmxReporter.java:85)
at org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics.registerMetric(Metrics.java:568)
at org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Sensor.add(Sensor.java:246)
at org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Sensor.add(Sensor.java:227)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.BufferPool.(BufferPool.java:84)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:408)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:299)
at org.apache.atlas.kafka.KafkaNotification.getOrCreateProducer(KafkaNotification.java:356)
at org.apache.atlas.kafka.KafkaNotification.sendInternal(KafkaNotification.java:262)
at org.apache.atlas.notification.AbstractNotification.send(AbstractNotification.java:93)
at org.apache.atlas.hook.AtlasHook$3.run(AtlasHook.java:207)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
at org.apache.atlas.hook.AtlasHook.notifyEntitiesInternal(AtlasHook.java:212)
at org.apache.atlas.hook.AtlasHook$2.run(AtlasHook.java:170)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
23/10/31 16:35:05 ERROR metrics.Metrics: Error when registering metric on org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission" "register")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:585)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.checkMBeanTrustPermission(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1848)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:322)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
at org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter.reregister(JmxReporter.java:167)
at org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter.metricChange(JmxReporter.java:85)
at org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics.registerMetric(Metrics.java:568)
at org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Sensor.add(Sensor.java:246)
at org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Sensor.add(Sensor.java:227)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.BufferPool.(BufferPool.java:84)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:408)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:299)
at org.apache.atlas.kafka.KafkaNotification.getOrCreateProducer(KafkaNotification.java:356)
at org.apache.atlas.kafka.KafkaNotification.sendInternal(KafkaNotification.java:262)
at org.apache.atlas.notification.AbstractNotification.send(AbstractNotification.java:93)
at org.apache.atlas.hook.AtlasHook$3.run(AtlasHook.java:207)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
at org.apache.atlas.hook.AtlasHook.notifyEntitiesInternal(AtlasHook.java:212)
at org.apache.atlas.hook.AtlasHook$2.run(AtlasHook.java:170)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
I have add  permission javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission "register"  to
$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.policy